# I cannot access my app hosted on aws with the ec2 public IP address

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs

So I have pushed two images to AWS ECR, one for the front end app, another for the back end. The front end app has a nginx serving a react app, and listening on port 80. While the back end app is listening on port 8080, to listen for requests from FE.

I now created a ECS task definition based on this two image. ECS created three EC2 instances for me, the main one is the ECS instance, the others i guess is instances that ECS created to ensure the desired number of task are running. The issue right now is, I cannot access the main one with the public IP address from my browser. However, when I ssh into either one of the other two EC2 instances, I can ping and curl and gets response from `127.0.0.1`.

Things I've looked into already:

1. The inbound rules. I have set two inbound rules in the security group, one is set to `Type` `HTTP`, `Source` set to `custom 0.0.0.0/0`, which I assume means any traffic. The other inbound rule is `Custom TCP`, port range `8080`, and `Source` is the current security group. Which I assume means the front end request to back end.
2. Docker logs in the ecs-created instance(non-main instance). I do get GET requests when I `ping` or `curl` in the EC2 instance, but not from my local browser
3. Nginx error and access logs. I've sshed into the EC2 instance, and `docker exec` into the container, I see nothing in the nginx access log and error log.

Here are my port mappings from the task definition, although I don't think this is the issue, since I can ping it in the ec2 instance.

```
"portMappings": [
    {
        "hostPort": 80,
        "protocol": "tcp",
        "containerPort": 80
    }
],
```

Also here is the nginx.conf

```
worker_processes 4;

events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    server {
        listen 80;
        root  /usr/share/nginx/html;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;

        location / {
            try_files $uri /index.html;
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        }
    }
}
```

Any help or recommendation would be appreciated, thanks!!

Comment: Is your backend server configured to listen on 127.0.0.1 (loopback only) or 0.0.0.0 (all interfaces)?

Comment: Hmm, currently it's listening on 0.0.0.0. Should I change it to 127.0.0.1?

Comment: No, 0.0.0.0 is correct and means all interfaces (i.e. it can be reached from outside the host itself). So the issue is something else.